# Комментируется любой php код как исправить?

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста. Инспектирую элемент. Вижу что код php закомментирован. По какой причине такое может происходить? Файл в формате php. Страница находится на хостинге. Заранее спасибо за ответ.
До:

```
 $text = "Сегодня хороший день";
        $content = "<div class='item-card'>
           <div class='item-name'><?=$text;?></div>
         </div>
```

После:

```
<div class="item-name"><!--?=Сегодня хороший день;?--></div>
```

Comment: $text в двойных кавычках при присваивании переменой не надо оборачивать в <?= ;?>

Comment: учитывая ваш предыдущий вопрос и сопоставляя с этим, очень вам рекомендую изучать пхп системно, а не решая задачи точечно через вопрос/ответ. Лучше понимать что делаешь и делать меньше, чем делать много не понимая, что делаешь. Удачи!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все банально просто:

```
$text = "Сегодня хороший день";
$content = "<div class='item-card'>
              <div class='item-name'>
                 ".$text."
              </div>
           </div>";
```

Или так (работает только с двойными кавычками):

```
$text = "Сегодня хороший день";
$content = "<div class='item-card'>
              <div class='item-name'>
                 {$text}
              </div>
           </div>";
```

Comment: `{$text}` - а тут скобки не лишние?

Comment: @Qwertiy и так и так можно, подробнее тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/5368897/7860529

Comment: @Qwertiy, неа, обычно конечно они используются для вызова через массив `{$array['key']}` - но и без них.

Comment: Хм.. А тогда что такое `${text}`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, я понятия не имею, что это: `${text}`, скорее это, не будет работать и выдаст `Undefined txt`, а вот это: `{$object->property}` или же `{$object->array['key']}`, работает на ура.

Comment: @Qwertiy например у тебя есть строка `echo "He drank some juice made of $juices.";`, но переменная у тебя `juice`, тогда делаем так `echo "He drank some juice made of ${juice}s.";`.

Comment: @Qwertiy `Если интерпретатор встречает знак доллара ($), он захватывает так много символов, сколько возможно, чтобы сформировать правильное имя переменной. Если вы хотите точно определить конец имени, заключайте имя переменной в фигурные скобки. ` Вот и доков

Comment: @And будет работать, выше написал

Comment: @And честно не совсем понял, если вы про пример в ответе, то будет работать http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c5fc21c495e812a1ce9399e12119c0bbd04842dd

Comment: @Qwertiy Хотя нет, я ошибся, работать будет, если задать переменную типа `$txt` а после сделать `${txt}`.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev, вы серьезно??? это же мой пример.... странно, что вы, не читаете ответы и тот кто их пишет.

Comment: @And вы говорите что `${text}` работать не будет. Не будет работать в контексте чего? Я привёл пример на основе вашего кода, но только с `${text}` и показываю что будет работать. Не пойму, что вы так отреагировали....

Comment: Ладно, давай так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/987872/178988. // cc @AlexanderSemikashev

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev, вроде как доллар не часть имени и по твоему описанию получится моя версия с фигурной скобкой после него, а не до?

Comment: @Qwertiy так давай подытожу. Есть простой такой вариант `${text}` удобен тем что можно вывести так `echo "Example ${text}ing.";` или прям выражение запихать можно `${trim('x')}`. То есть всё норм выведется. Это пример простого синтаксиса. А есть более сложный, когда нужно например работать с элементами массива или объектами, то записывать можно так `echo "Этот квадрат шириной {$square->width}00 сантиметров.";`  Более подробно написано в доках, думаю там понятно всё https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing