# В чём разница между {$x} и ${x}?

Tags: php

В php есть минимум 3 способа вставки переменной в строку:

https://ideone.com/sN22RT

```
$x = 'test';
echo("$x {$x} ${x}");
```

Выводится

```
test test test
```

То, что `${x}` и `{$x}` (в отличие от `$x`) можно использовать перед буквенноцифровым символом понятно, а чем сами эти два способа отличаются между собой?

Comment: `${x}` работает шустрей чем `{$x}`, который, в свою очередь, работает быстрей чем конкантенация. Первый случай используется для строгого указания имени переменной. `$x = 'y' ... " $xxyy "` - вернет ошибку, но если указать строго имя переменной `$x = 'y' ... " ${x}xyy "` то ошибки не будет.

Comment: `{$x}` - в некоторых случаях фигурные скобки заменяют двойные ковычки для вывода, тогда как так `${x}` уже будет ошибка

Comment: @InDevX дайте контакты вашего дилера

Comment: @Ипатьев 937-99-92, круглосуточно

Comment: @Ипатьев вот что интересное нашел по вашей же [ссылке](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#120160)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отличие в том, что `{$x}` - это фича именно двойных кавычек, [формат обращения к переменной](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

А `${x}` - это это [переменные переменные](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php), общий для языка синтаксис формирования имени переменной из выражения. И позволяет писать внутри фигурных скобок практически любой код на пхп:

```
function y() {return 'x';}
$x = $y = 'test';
$z = 'w';
echo ${++$z}, " ", ${trim('x')}," ", ${y()}, " ", ${'x'.''};
```

*но вот то, что он работает в закавыченных строках тоже* -

```
echo " ${++$z} ${trim('x')} ${y()} ${'x'.''}";
```

это для меня сюрприз. И выглядит это несколько жутковато. Но, видимо, это результат проведенной Никитой работы по унификации языка.

Comment: Скопипастил на ideone из интереса: https://ideone.com/9Ti8Gm

Comment: Я тут еще круче наковырял, https://3v4l.org/DQVtN :)